Role of the 3-form in 11D Supergravity and How do matter and gauge fields arise from compactifying 11th dimension on $S^1$ vs $S^1 \times Z_2$
I’ve been reading about the compactifications of 11-dimensional supergravity and their connections to type IIA and $E_8 \times E_8$ heterotic string theories in 10 dimensions. I’m particularly interested in the role of the 3-form gauge field and the emergence of matter and gauge fields.
First, what role does the 3-form field $C_{\mu \nu \rho}$ play in the 11 dimensional theory and how does it couple to the Graviton, Gravitino and branes?
Second, in the scenario where the 11th dimension is compactified on a circle ($S^1$), how do matter fields arise and what happens to the 11D fields (the metric, gravitino, 3-form) and what is the resulting field spectrum?
Third, the dimension is compactified on an orbifold ($S^1 \times Z_2$). As a result, $E_8$ gauge fields and symmetry emerge on 2 boundaries defined by the $Z_2$ factor. Can someone clarify what the mechanism from which these gauge fields and their associated gauge symmetry emerge is? And what is the resulting field spectrum?
Finally, how does the $Z_2$ factor change the way new fields arise from the existing ones and what is the difference between the two theories?
I would appreciate a detailed explanation, particularly one that incorporates the relevant mathematical formalism and highlights the physical intuition behind these mechanisms.

Are you familiar with compactification in general and just want an explicit example of how it works here or do you want a general explanation how field dof show up after compactification? If the latter is the case a quick Google search for kaluza Klein compactification should give you a log of good resources to answer that part of you question

@ThomasTappeiner I do have a general understanding of Kaluza Klein compactification and I do want an explicit example of how this works

Have you put in any effort to understand these things? For me at least it does not appear to be reasonable to write a lengthy derivation when every textbook or paper on this subject probably is doing a better job explaining it. IMO it would be better to ask a little bit more specific questions.
